# Но(,) если – нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, запятые, союзы

Нужна ли запятая в "но если"?

*Но(,) если верно уловил из разговоров, Сергей уехал сегодня в Сочи.*

*Но(,) если ты выполнил заказ, я готов заплатить.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая ситуация хорошо описана в справочнике Розенталя (не буду повторять ссылку, она уже есть в одном из ответов).

• В первом предложении конструкция "если верно уловил из разговоров" очень похожа на вставочную. Запятая после "но", как правило, в этом случае не ставится (см. примечание).
Я бы тоже не стала ставить запятую:
*Но если верно уловил из разговоров, Сергей уехал сегодня в Сочи.*

•• Во втором предложении пунктуация зависит от воли и задумки автора.
Сравните:
***Но если** ты вернешь мне золото, я обещаю тебе список уничтожить и забыть о нем* (Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок);
***Но, если** ты так считаешь, через день-другой его можно на всякий случай отравить...* (Николай Дежнев. Год бродячей собаки).

В Нацкорпусе можно посмотреть предложения с такой комбинацией ([но если ты...](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkIqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHwodChsKA3JlcRIUChLQvdC%2BINC10YHQu9C4INGC0YswAQ==)).
В подавляющем большинстве случаев запятой нет.

Answer (score 4):

Возможны оба варианта пунктуации: с запятой и без неё.
Всё зависит от пауз, акцентов, интонации, контекста.

[**Запятая на стыке двух союзов**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140) (справочник Розенталя)

> **3)** после союза ***но*** запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.: ***Но, если** далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку* (Сим.); ***Но когда** он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране* (Павл.)

Answer (score 2):

Да, скорее всего нужна, в противном случае было бы: но если ты выполнил заказ - я готов заплатить. Хотя можно и просто через одну запятую. В общем зависит от того, к чему относится "но"(ко второй части или это "но если") и какую интонацию хочется передать.

Например:

*Ты плохо себя вел, но если ты изменишься, то я тебе дам подарок.*

Но если верно уловил из разговоров,(то) Сергей уехал сегодня в Сочи.(обычное повествование)

Или

Но Сергей уехал сегодня из Сочи.(возражение, в диалоге например)

И так и так - можно.

*и не после НО, а перед ЕСЛИ.

Comment: @Буратино *Ты плохо себя вел, **но если** ты изменишься, **то** я тебе дам подарок.*  Это предложение ну никак не подходит. У нас комбинация **но если** стоит в начале предложения, а слова **то** вообще нет. При наличии соотносительного слова "то" между "но" и "если" запятая не ставится.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова слова "то" - нет, поэтому я и написал, что, скорее всего, нужна запятая. Но если "то" подразумевается, то может и не нужна.  Но, если только позволяет интонация, то не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Решение зависит **от контекста,** и можно предположить, что оба предложения имеют два варианта решения.

(1)  Я планировал с ним  встретиться. *Но, / **если верно уловил из разговоров,** //  Сергей уехал сегодня в Сочи.*

*Если верно уловил из разговоров* – здесь источник информации. Союз НО относится к предыдущему **контексту**. Но возможен вариант, когда НО будет относиться первой части предложения.

(2) Эта информация сейчас уже не актуальна. **Но если ты выполнил заказ,** // я готов заплатить.

Здесь такая же ситуация. **В заданном контексте** союз НО относится к придаточному условия, но другой вариант тоже возможен.

Comment: – *Нет, я ничего не утверждаю. Но если верно уловил из разговоров, Сергей уехал в Сочи.*

Comment: В обоих предложениях может быть два варианта.

Comment: Вероятно, да. Но хорошо бы эти варианты указать в ответе. Правила, примеры из Нацкорпуса не дают такого понимания темы, как реальное сравнение  вариантов в своих примерах. Ну мне так кажется.

Comment: Это да, хорошо. Но пусть человек сам выберет, что ему ближе, что ему нужно выразить.

Comment: А если посмотреть с другой стороны... Мы же не знаем человека. Я даю выбор. Если человек знает назначение запятой, знаком с паузой, если сможет ещё хоть раз произнести предложения с учётом своего, только ему известного, контекста, – он сделает выбор. И вот результат моей помощи. А если перейдёт по ссылке, то, вполне вероятно, откроет для себя более глубокий мир.

Comment: Может быть... Вы, наверное, правы.

Comment: Sharon, вводные слова и сочетания тоже не могут являться объяснением запятой, они в этом случае не хуже других, им позволено и так, и так. А в правилах даже написано: "после присоединительного союза, если дальше следует вводное слово (сочетание, предложение), запятая, как правило, не ставится: ***И вероятно,** вы его не дождётесь; **Но может быть,** вопрос ещё не рассматривался*".

Comment: Я не доказываю, просто в заданном  контексте предложение используется как отдельный источник информации.

Comment: Ну вот, хорошо, что убрали "вводные". Теперь можно +

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю немного рассуждений по теме.

Что является **главным ориентиром** при выборе **факультативных** решений?

1. По правилам запятая может ставиться или не ставиться, а в качестве ориентира предлагается **интонация** (наличие паузы).

**Правило Розенталя:** 3) после союза ***но*** запятая ставится **при наличии паузы** между союзами и не ставится, **если паузы нет;** ср.: ***Но, если** далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку* (Сим.); ***Но когда** он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране* (Павл.).

2. Вроде бы не очень надежный ориентир, это как бы уже **проверка** выбранного решения. А главным фактором при выборе знака во всех задачах является **смысл.** Здесь он такой: **к чему относится союз НО**, к главному или придаточному предложению?

Это надо смотреть по **своему** конкретному предложению, или же угадать контекст (если предложение одно). А автор должен **выбрать**  нужное решение. **По смыслу!** Все остальное потом.

3. Но есть еще один вариант решения/ответа: посмотреть в  Нацкорпусе **частотность** сочетания "***но если***". В подавляющем большинстве случаев запятая не ставится. Так что, **делаем как все?**

Так тоже можно, но это как сказать... А что если "эти все" друг у друга **списывают**, вот и множится один-единственный и подавляющий вариант?

4. Посмотреть, конечно, не вредно, но потом надо примерить вариант с запятой **для семантики** своего предложения. А вдруг не сойдется? И структура предложения тоже проверяется по наличию паузы (удобно ли с паузой прочитать).

И вот когда все эти факторы **не противоречат** друг другу, можно окончательно принять решение. **Долго очень?** Тогда выбирайте нужный вариант **по смыслу**, то есть по своему контексту. Это же **ваше** предложение!

5. Я приведу **пример такого выбора** по ответу и комментарию к нему.

(1) *Я планировал с ним встретиться. **Но, / если** верно уловил из разговоров, // Сергей уехал сегодня в Сочи.*  Подобран **контекст**, сделан **однозначный** выбор.

(2) Но предложен **другой контекст**, и решение **меняется**: *Нет, я ничего не утверждаю. **Но если** верно уловил из разговоров, Сергей уехал в Сочи.*

**P.S.**  Думаю, что **интересная** получилась история. Кстати, сама я голосовала за Александра, это  был мой выбор **правильного** ответа. И именно с ним мы подбирали этот контекст.